missing run icon and execute icon in my vs code when i am using .sql file
I have a problem with my vs code when I am using a .SQL file
it does not show the run icon in the vscode screen and I have to select some lines and run but other people have a lot of run icons in vs code screen
Does anybody know how to have these icons in my vs code?
I installed MySQL extension in my vs code
actually, all of my friends are using MySQL extension and they don't have this problem
this screenshot is not mine, I just want to say what I missed


why... is your screenshot showing a file in the user data directory's globalStorage directory? 2) please give the extension ID of the extension you installed and ask you friends to make sure that's the exact same extension by comparing extension ID and seeing if the execute code lens goes away if they disable that extension and reload extensions.


this screenshot is in the extension's details, and its name is
MySQL
v7.5.2
Weijan Chen
I asked her and she said
I disabled it but the "Run button" is still there
I think my problem is in vscode's settings @starball
